# How to create a kusto activity in data factory pipeline using c# .net sdk

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a pipeline with Kusto activity using .net code. I am not able to find any KustoActivity class in ADF's DLL. I am also not able to find anywhere in the Kusto's .net reference documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models?view=azure-dotnet .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the library and method related to Azure Data explorer(Including Kusto)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory -Version 3.0.1
```

I would recommend you to install below packages in your [project for pipeline.

```js
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

Here you can find all the module available in Azure.management.DataFactory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models?view=azure-dotnet

[AzureDataExplorerLinkedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.azuredataexplorerlinkedservice?view=azure-dotnet) is the class you would be interested in by which you can explore Kusto in dot net pipeline.

Hope it helps.